# mousedown not working on layer in kineticjs

Tags: html, kineticjs

i have been working with a kineticjs game where i have kept  one layer for the background, one for the player's character, and others,all together having the same kinetic stage.

Then I ran into a situation where I needed a shape of one layer where i can add multiple events,but though the mouse event are working on the stage they are not getting called on particular shape.I have tried layer.on('mousedown',function(),false);
its not working

Comment: shouldn't you be calling the mousedown on the particular shape you are trying to modify instead of calling it on the layer?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try shape.on('mousedown', function().....); as Ani says